# Create a chart from video color palettes in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video, frame

I'm trying to create a chart with averaged colors of each frame of a video. Then I want to stitch them together to create color spectrum.

So first of all, I load a video and calculate average color frame by frame and I stock all three RGB values in three vectors to finally create a synthesis image.

```
v = VideoReader('video.mkv');
numFrames = ceil(v.FrameRate*v.Duration);

% R G B Color channels
stockRed = zeros(1,numFrames+1);
stockGreen = zeros(1,numFrames+1);
stockBlue = zeros(1,numFrames+1);

it = 1;

while hasFrame(v)

    video = readFrame(v);

    redChannel = video(:, :, 1);
    greenChannel = video(:, :, 2);
    blueChannel = video(:, :, 3);

    %% RGB average
    redMean = mean2(redChannel);
    stockRed(1,it) = redMean;

    greenMean = mean2(greenChannel);
    stockGreen(1,it) = greenMean;

    blueMean = mean2(blueChannel);
    stockBlue(1,it) = blueMean;

    it = it + 1;
end
%% Creating image
synthesis = cat(3,stockRed,stockGreen,stockBlue);
imsave(synthesis,'synthesis.png')
```

The problem is that even if my synthesis matrix seems to contain correct values, synthesis.png is black and white and doesn't seem to be very representative of the video.

What could help ?

Comment: Convert `video` to `double` class to make it consistent with the rest of the variables,i.e. replace the line `video=readFrame(v);` with `video=im2double(readFrame(v));`

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first, why `imsave` and not `imwrite`? As far as I can tell, `imsave` is for saving images displayed in a figure.

The other thing to be careful of is dynamic ranges - the documentation for `imwrite` states

> If A is a grayscale or RGB color image of data type double or single, then imwrite assumes that the dynamic range is [0,1] and automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as 8-bit values. If the data in A is single, convert A to double before writing to a GIF or TIFF file.

So you will want to ensure the values of your synthesis do indeed lie between [0,1], and if not, you should scale them into that range, e.g. by `synthesis = synthesis./255` if you have 8 bit values in your video frames.